# How can I reduce the execution time required by SPECK, SPIHT and EZW?

Tags: matlab, image-compression, entropy, dwt

I am compressing images using DWT and DWT based entropy coders like SPECK, SPIHT and EZW using MATLAB. However, the execution time required by these entropy coders is too high. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Can you reveal your source code?